# Would an ASP:DataGrid control be a good choice for this?

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms

I have been tasked with converting a Classic ASP project to an ASP.Net project.  One of the pages in the original project uses a frameset to build a table that consists of a header and body:

```
<frameset rows="175, 300, *" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" border="0" id="frmCommentReport">
        <frame src="commentStatusReportHeader.asp?CourseId=<%=Request("CourseId")%>&Id=<%=Request("Id")%>" scrolling="yes" name="header" marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 border=0 />
        <frame src="commentStatusReportBody.asp?CourseId= %=Request("CourseId")%>&Id=<%=Request("Id")%>" scrolling="yes" name="body" marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 />
```

Both the header and body of the table is buit from vbscript embedded in each page.  The header information comes from one datasource.  The body information comes from another.

What I'd like to do, instead of using two frames (or even one frame for that matter) is just combine the information on an .aspx page in the form of an ASP:DataGrid control.

Being a neophyte ASP.Net person, I was wondering if using the DataGrid control would be the way to go?  Or, is there another, more preferable method that someone could suggest.

I appreciate any advice and pointers.

The result looks like this:
[image]

Comment: FYI, this is ASP.NET, not ASP Classic.

Comment: Sorry, John.  I included ASP Classic tag since the actual header and body are built from vbscript on an .asp page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off using simple asp:Repeaters for this. That way you can fully control the CSS and HTML you use to shape the user interface. It is possible to do it with an asp:DataGrid but the asp:DataGrid is too rigid.

What you would do is have nested repeaters:

```
<table>
    <asp:Repeater id="rpt1" runat="server>
      <tr><td>
         <table>
            <asp:Repeater ID="rpt2" runat="server">
               <tr><td></td></tr>
             </asp:Repeater>
          </table>
       </td></tr>
     </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

Then in your code behind you would bind the parent rpt1 and then in the rpt1.ItemDataBound:

```
     Protected Sub rpt1_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rpt1.ItemDataBound
        If (item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem) Then
            Dim rpt2 As Repeater = item.FindControl("rpt2")
            //Bind More Data
        End If
      End Sub
```

This is, obviously, a simple example that you will have to expand upon to finesse the desired U.I. but hopefully you can see how flexible this approach can be. Also you don't have to bind some massive pivoted data set to the repeaters as you would have to do with the asp:DataGrid

Comment: Sounds like this will work nicely for what I have to do.  I've used Repeaters before (for displaying different images, like search page results on Google) so I'm at least familiar enough with them to move forward on this.  I only thought of using a DataGrid because of a suggestion from a site I was reading on displaying tabled data.  I appreciate the answer!

Comment: No problem! Ya love using asp:repeaters and clean HTML and CSS. Just feel like I am in control as opposed to the asp:DataGrid, which can be very powerful but sometimes too cumbersome and rigid for custom U.I.'s